# Application.properties file not being tracked by git

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a Java Spring project that has application.properties file in the resources folder. When I try to commit it to git it doesn't show in the list of  changed files. I am using SourceTree. This is my .gitignore. I am using intellij community edition.

```
/target/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar

### STS ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans
.sts4-cache

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr

### NetBeans ###
/nbproject/private/
/build/
/nbbuild/
/dist/
/nbdist/
 /.nb-gradle/
```

I want application.properties to be tracked.

Comment: Have you done a git add?

Comment: Try running `git status` in a terminal. What's the output?

Comment: git status doesn't show any changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had .properties ignored in a global .gitignore